# Querying rows by index in S3 Select

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-select

With mysql the following code:

```
SELECT * from TABLE limit 5, 10
```

would pull the 5th through 10th rows of the table. What is the equivalent for doing this through the SQL engine in S3 select (PrestoDB I believe)? Is there a rownumber constructor or operator that works with S3 select?

Comment: Amazon Athena uses Presto, but I don't think Amazon S3 Select uses it. It only operates on one file at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The S3 Select documentation is at: [SQL Reference for Amazon S3 Select and Amazon Glacier Select - Amazon Glacier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/s3-glacier-select-sql-reference.html)

The `LIMIT` clause is documented as:

> `LIMIT number`
>
> The `LIMIT` clause limits the number of records that you want the query to return based on *number*.

So, not available.

Comment: Got it. Also looks like there's a `row_numbers`  SQL function that works in Athena but also isn't currently supported in S3 select, which really sucks.

Answer (score 2):

It's not available as a feature, but this is how we did for our project.

Before uploading the CSV files to S3, we just added a field row_index in CSV.

```
row_index, field1
1, a, 
2, b,
3, c,
4, d,
5, d,
```

So the query

```
Select * from Table Limit 1, 4
```

Will be replaced with

```
Select * from s3 where row_index >= 1 and row_index <= 4
```

Remember, the scan cost will increase if your files are too large. But you can consider splitting your files into smaller chunks for better querying with low cost.

For example, a file with 100k-rows.csv can be split into 10 files.

```
1-10000-rows.csv
10001-20000-rows.csv
...
```

Then you can read the `offset`, `limit` variable to find which file should be queried for your rows. For example

```
to fetch rows 200- 300 - You will query the 1-10000-rows.csv
to fetch rows 12000- 12500  - You will query the 10001-20000-rows.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

According to their documentation, PrestoDB supports a LIMIT clause but only with one argument for row count. It does not support a second argument for offset.

Read the docs for yourself: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html